# Is it possible to return the rows between row 'x' and row 'y'?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple question regrading MySQL. Is it possible to return the rows between row 'x' and row 'y'? It's sort of hard to explain - for the sake of an example: Return rows 6 through 10, excluding rows 1-5 and rows 11+. Thanks! ;D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html). Remember to combine it with ORDER BY for the results to make any sense.

```
SELECT fields, ...
FROM table
ORDER BY something_sensible
LIMIT 5, 5
```

(Start from row 6, take 5 rows)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 5, 5
```

Comment: I would like to point out that is not correct according to Joe's 6-10 example. EDIT: Until it is edited to match other answers.

Comment: I think the question was pretty specific in the example they were looking for. As an answer, I would think it would need to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5, 5
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html and look at `LIMIT` section

Answer (score 0):

From the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select * from employees order by emp_id;
+--------+-----------------+---------+
| emp_id | name            | boss_id |
+--------+-----------------+---------+
|      1 | f00             |    NULL |
|      2 | ali later       |       1 |
|      3 | megan fox       |       1 |
|      4 | jessica alba    |       3 |
|      5 | eva longoria    |       3 |
|      6 | keira knightley |       5 |
|      7 | liv tyler       |       6 |
|      8 | sophie marceau  |       6 |
+--------+-----------------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from employees order by emp_id limit 2,4;
+--------+-----------------+---------+
| emp_id | name            | boss_id |
+--------+-----------------+---------+
|      3 | megan fox       |       1 |
|      4 | jessica alba    |       3 |
|      5 | eva longoria    |       3 |
|      6 | keira knightley |       5 |
+--------+-----------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use an Auto Increment field? Or you can use LIMIT keyword like:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE LIMIT 0, 5
```

This will show records 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Auto increment has nothing to do with this particular question, and your example does not in any way answer the question, except the 5.